# Webkitdirectory Upload Issue

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am using Webkitdirectory to upload a folder.

I am able to select the folder and upload.
But can anyone explain where does the uploaded physical file stored?

```
<input type="file" id="_idUploadFiles" name="fileList" webkitdirectory ="multiple" class="btn btn-primary" /> 

        <script>
            document.getElementById("filepicker").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
              let output = document.getElementById("listing");
              let files = event.target.files;

              for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                let item = document.createElement("li");
                item.innerHTML = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
                output.appendChild(item);
              };
            }, false);
       </script>
```